# JavaScript function to convert keyCodes into characters

Tags: javascript

Are there any built in functions in any JavaScript framework to convert keyCodes into characters? Which accounts the shift property, so it will return the correct characters.

Or we just have to build our own function ?

Comment: `String.fromCharCode()` ?

Comment: I do not think it is a duplicate. `fromCharCode` converts from *character* codes, not from *key* codes (as requested explicitly here).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `String.fromCharCode()`

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fromCharCode) :

**Syntax** : `String.fromCharCode(num1, ..., numN)`

**Parameters** : `num1, ..., numN`  (A sequence of numbers that are Unicode values.)

> This method returns a string and not a String object.
>
> Because fromCharCode is a static method of String, you always use it as String.fromCharCode(), rather than as a method of a String object you created.

---

### **Update**:

Here I made a function that would do what you want : **http://jsbin.com/ukukuq/2/**

[(Code)](http://jsbin.com/ukukuq/2/edit)

```
function keyDownEvent(e) {
    var other = {};
    var output= {};
    output['meta'] = {};
    var html = '';

    e = (e) ? e : ((event) ? event : null);

    if (e) {
        output['keyCode']   = (e.keyCode) ? e.keyCode : 'N/A';
        output['charCode'] = (e.charCode) ? e.charCode : 'N/A';
        output['meta']['shift']     =   e.shiftKey  ? true : false;
        output['meta']['ctrl']      =   e.ctrlKey   ? true : false;
        output['meta']['alt']       =   e.altKey    ? true : false;
        output['meta']['meta']      =   e.metaKey   ? true : false;

        html = document.getElementById('output')
        return html.innerHTML += '<pre>keyDown : ' + JSON.stringify(output) + '</pre>';
    } else {
        return 'error';
    }
}

function keyPressEvent(e) {
    var other = {};
    var output= {};
    var html = '';

    e = (e) ? e : ((event) ? event : null);

    if (e) {
        output['keyCode']   = (e.keyCode) ? e.keyCode : 'N/A';
        output['charCode'] = (e.charCode) ? e.charCode : 'N/A';

        html = document.getElementById('output')
        return html.innerHTML += '<pre>keyPress : ' + JSON.stringify(output) + ' Character : <strong>' +  String.fromCharCode(output['charCode']) + '</strong></pre><hr/>';
    } else {
        return 'error';
    }
}

var test = document.getElementById('test');
test.onkeydown = keyDownEvent;
test.onkeypress = keyPressEvent;
```

---

Comment: what I mean is from keycode not charcode, anyway it seems there are no one builds this functionality

Answer (score 0):

I have my own function too, I modified the script from http://www.cambiaresearch.com/articles/15/javascript-char-codes-key-codes

```
        function convertKeyCode(evt) {
            var chara = "";
            var keyCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;
            var shift = evt.shiftKey;
            //if (keyCode == 8)
            //  chara = "backspace";
            //  backspace
            //if (keyCode == 9)
            //  chara = "tab";
            //  tab
            //if (keyCode == 13)
            //  chara = "enter";
            //  enter
            //if (keyCode == 16)
            //  chara = "shift";
            //  shift
            //if (keyCode == 17)
            //  chara = "ctrl";
            //  ctrl
            //if (keyCode == 18)
            //  chara = "alt";
            //  alt
            if (keyCode == 19)
                chara = "pause/break";
            //  pause/break
            //if (keyCode == 20)
            //  chara = "caps lock";
            //  caps lock
            //if (keyCode == 27)
            //  chara = "escape";
            //  escape
            //if (keyCode == 33)
            //  chara = "page up";
            // page up, to avoid displaying alternate character and confusing people
            //if (keyCode == 34)
            //  chara = "page down";
            // page down
            //if (keyCode == 35)
            //  chara = "end";
            // end
            //if (keyCode == 36)
            //  chara = "home";
            // home
            //if (keyCode == 37)
            //  chara = "left arrow";
            // left arrow
            //if (keyCode == 38)
            //  chara = "up arrow";
            // up arrow
            //if (keyCode == 39)
            //  chara = "right arrow";
            // right arrow
            //if (keyCode == 40)
            //  chara = "down arrow";
            // down arrow
            //if (keyCode == 45)
            //  chara = "insert";
            // insert
            //if (keyCode == 46)
            //  chara = "delete";
            // delete
            // Alphanumeric
            if (keyCode == 48)
                chara = (shift) ? ")" : "0";
            if (keyCode == 49)
                chara = (shift) ? "!" : "1";
            if (keyCode == 50)
                chara = (shift) ? "@" : "2";
            if (keyCode == 51)
                chara = (shift) ? "#" : "3";
            if (keyCode == 52)
                chara = (shift) ? "$" : "4";
            if (keyCode == 53)
                chara = (shift) ? "%" : "5";
            if (keyCode == 54)
                chara = (shift) ? "^" : "6";
            if (keyCode == 55)
                chara = (shift) ? "&" : "7";
            if (keyCode == 56)
                chara = (shift) ? "*" : "8";
            if (keyCode == 57)
                chara = (shift) ? "(" : "9";

            if (keyCode == 65)
                chara = (shift) ? "A" : "a";
            if (keyCode == 66)
                chara = (shift) ? "B" : "b";
            if (keyCode == 67)
                chara = (shift) ? "C" : "c";
            if (keyCode == 68)
                chara = (shift) ? "D" : "d";
            if (keyCode == 69)
                chara = (shift) ? "E" : "e";
            if (keyCode == 70)
                chara = (shift) ? "F" : "f";
            if (keyCode == 71)
                chara = (shift) ? "G" : "g";
            if (keyCode == 72)
                chara = (shift) ? "H" : "h";
            if (keyCode == 73)
                chara = (shift) ? "I" : "i";
            if (keyCode == 74)
                chara = (shift) ? "J" : "j";
            if (keyCode == 75)
                chara = (shift) ? "K" : "k";
            if (keyCode == 76)
                chara = (shift) ? "L" : "l";
            if (keyCode == 77)
                chara = (shift) ? "M" : "m";
            if (keyCode == 78)
                chara = (shift) ? "N" : "n";
            if (keyCode == 79)
                chara = (shift) ? "O" : "o";
            if (keyCode == 80)
                chara = (shift) ? "P" : "p";
            if (keyCode == 81)
                chara = (shift) ? "Q" : "q";
            if (keyCode == 82)
                chara = (shift) ? "R" : "r";
            if (keyCode == 83)
                chara = (shift) ? "S" : "s";
            if (keyCode == 84)
                chara = (shift) ? "T" : "t";
            if (keyCode == 85)
                chara = (shift) ? "U" : "u";
            if (keyCode == 86)
                chara = (shift) ? "V" : "v";
            if (keyCode == 87)
                chara = (shift) ? "W" : "w";
            if (keyCode == 88)
                chara = (shift) ? "X" : "x";
            if (keyCode == 89)
                chara = (shift) ? "Y" : "y";
            if (keyCode == 90)
                chara = (shift) ? "Z" : "z";
            // Alphanumeric
            //if (keyCode == 91)
            //  chara = "left window";
            // left window
            //if (keyCode == 92)
            //  chara = "right window";
            // right window
            if (keyCode == 93)
                chara = "select key";
            // select key
            //if (keyCode == 96)
            //  chara = "numpad 0";
            // numpad 0
            //if (keyCode == 97)
            //  chara = "numpad 1";
            // numpad 1
            //if (keyCode == 98)
            //  chara = "numpad 2";
            // numpad 2
            //if (keyCode == 99)
            //  chara = "numpad 3";
            // numpad 3
            //if (keyCode == 100)
            //  chara = "numpad 4";
            // numpad 4
            //if (keyCode == 101)
            //  chara = "numpad 5";
            // numpad 5
            //if (keyCode == 102)
            //  chara = "numpad 6";
            // numpad 6
            //if (keyCode == 103)
            //  chara = "numpad 7";
            // numpad 7
            //if (keyCode == 104)
            //  chara = "numpad 8";
            // numpad 8
            //if (keyCode == 105)
            //  chara = "numpad 9";
            // numpad 9
            //if (keyCode == 106)
            //  chara = "multiply";
            // multiply
            //if (keyCode == 107)
            //  chara = "add";
            // add
            //if (keyCode == 109)
            //  chara = "subtract";
            // subtract
            //if (keyCode == 110)
            //  chara = "decimal point";
            // decimal point
            //if (keyCode == 111)
            //  chara = "divide";
            // divide
            //if (keyCode == 112)
            //  chara = "F1";
            // F1
            //if (keyCode == 113)
            //  chara = "F2";
            // F2
            //if (keyCode == 114)
            //  chara = "F3";
            // F3
            //if (keyCode == 115)
            //  chara = "F4";
            // F4
            //if (keyCode == 116)
            //  chara = "F5";
            // F5
            //if (keyCode == 117)
            //  chara = "F6";
            // F6
            //if (keyCode == 118)
            //  chara = "F7";
            // F7
            //if (keyCode == 119)
            //  chara = "F8";
            // F8
            //if (keyCode == 120)
            //  chara = "F9";
            // F9
            //if (keyCode == 121)
            //  chara = "F10";
            // F10
            //if (keyCode == 122)
            //  chara = "F11";
            // F11
            //if (keyCode == 123)
            //  chara = "F12";
            // F12
            //if (keyCode == 144)
            //  chara = "num lock";
            // num lock
            //if (keyCode == 145)
            //  chara = "scroll lock";
            // scroll lock
            if (keyCode == 186)
                chara = ";";
            // semi-colon
            if (keyCode == 187)
                chara = "=";
            // equal-sign
            if (keyCode == 188)
                chara = ",";
            // comma
            if (keyCode == 189)
                chara = "-";
            // dash
            if (keyCode == 190)
                chara = ".";
            // period
            if (keyCode == 191)
                chara = "/";
            // forward slash
            if (keyCode == 192)
                chara = "`";
            // grave accent
            if (keyCode == 219)
                chara = (shift) ? "{" : "[";
            // open bracket
            if (keyCode == 220)
                chara = "\\";
            // back slash
            if (keyCode == 221)
                chara = (shift) ? "}" : "]";
            // close bracket
            if (keyCode == 222)
                chara = "'";
            // single quote

            return chara;

        }
```

Comment: I admire your hard work (if you typed all that out), but a good programming tip to consider is "if there is a bunch of repeating/similar code (like all those if statements), there is probably a more efficient way to do it." For example, to convert the keycodes 65 to 90, you could do: `var letterTyped = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"[e.keyCode-65];`