# grab the the alphanumeric character on keydown in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, key

Using the `keydown` event, I know we're able to get the key code using `e.which` or `e.keycode`, but I'm looking for a way to see what the letter was itself, not just the code. For example, if someone hit the letter "s", I want to return "s", not its code. Is there a cross-browser way to do that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript function to convert keyCodes into characters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13992111/javascript-function-to-convert-keycodes-into-characters)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can convert the ASCII character code to string with `String.fromCharCode(code)`.

Example:

```
$(document).keydown(function(e) {
    var code = e.which;

    $('body').append('key: ' + String.fromCharCode(code) + '<br/>');
});
```

[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/FgeFk/)

Comment: does jQuery normalise e.which?

Answer (score 3):

Here you go:

```
String.fromCharCode(e.which)
```

Answer (score 1):

here is the easy way;

```
    $(document).keydown(function(e) {
        var code = e.keycode;
        alert(code);
    });
```